# VBA, ADO.Connection and query parameters

Tags: vba, ado

I have excel VBA script:

```
Set cоnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "report"
Set rs = conn.Execute("select * from table" )
```

Script work fine, but i want to add parameter to it. For example " where (parentid = *myparam*)", where *myparam* setted outside query string. How can i do it?

Of course i can modify query string, but i think it not very wise.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to use an ADODB.Command object that you can add parameters to.  Here's basically what that looks like

```
Sub adotest()

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Cm As ADODB.Command
    Dim Pm As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim Rs as ADODB.Recordset

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "mystring"
    Set Cm = New ADODB.Command
    With Cm
        .ActiveConnection = Cn
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE parentid=?;"
        .CommandType = adCmdText

        Set Pm = .CreateParameter("parentid", adNumeric, adParamInput)
        Pm.Value = 1

        .Parameters.Append Pm

        Set Rs = .Execute
    End With

End Sub
```

The question mark in the CommandText is the placeholder for the parameter.  I believe, but I'm not positive, that the order you Append parameters must match the order of the questions marks (when you have more than one).  Don't be fooled that the parameter is named "parentid" because I don't think ADO cares about the name other than for identification.

Comment: I believe you are correct on the order of parameters. This tripped me up when I came from C# .Net and then coded VBScript.

Comment: Or you could just..
.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE parentid=" & myparam & ";"

Comment: @LuigiMackenzieC.Brito that defeats the purpose of using parameterized queries. Using concatenation of variables containing userinput data to build SQL query strings is a bad practice. (Because what if myparam = "parentid;SELECT * from userpasswords", or if the connecting user has write privileges: myparam ="parentid;insert into userpasswords..." or just even to be trolly, myparam="parentid;delete from table")

Comment: @cowbert SQL Injections yes. In my practice I used PHP to filter them out.

Comment: @LuigiMackenzieC.Brito -- Yet you didn't mention that with your comment, thus leaving the danger that someone could use your method without knowing about SQL Injections.  It's not a good practice to do string concat for queries, even if you somehow filtered out the dangerous code (which I highly doubt).

Answer (score 13):

Alternative example returning a command from a function:

```
Function BuildCommand(conn As ADODB.Connection) As ADODB.Command
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "Dave")
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = @name;"
    Set BuildCommand = cmd
End Function
```

A couple things to note:

1. When using `adVarChar` data type, the size argument to `cmd.CreateParameter` (e.g. 255) is required. Not supplying it results a run-time error 3708: Application-defined or object-defined error, as indicated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado):

   > If you specify a variable-length data type in the Type argument, you must either pass a Size argument or set the Size property of the Parameter object before appending it to the Parameters collection; otherwise, an error occurs.
2. If the `cmd.ActiveConnection` property is set when `cmd.CommandText` is set, and `cmd.CommandText` contains named parameters, `cmd.Parameters` will be populated accordingly. Calling `cmd.Parameters.Append` afterwards could result in duplicates. For example:

   ```
   cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
   cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
   Debug.Print cmd.Parameters.Count ' 0

   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = @name;"
   Debug.Print cmd.Parameters.Count ' 1

   cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "Dave")
   Debug.Print cmd.Parameters.Count ' 2
   ```

   I believe this is what is meant in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/commandtext-property-ado), which is slightly inaccurate:

   > If the Prepared property of the Command object is set to True and the Command object is bound to an open connection when you set the CommandText property, ADO prepares the query (that is, a compiled form of the query that is stored by the provider) when you call the Execute or Open methods.

   As a workaround, either set `cmd.CommandText` or `cmd.ActiveConnection` after adding parameters.

Comment: whenever I try to do this, I always get runtime error `Must Declare the scalar variable "@name"`

Comment: This makes for cleaner looking code when there are several parameters to set. Thanks.

Comment: For this to work, I think you would also need [`cmd.NamedParameters = True`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/namedparameters-property-ado) and the connection must use an [ADO provider which supports named parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types#working-with-parameter-placeholders) (e.g. SqlClient, not ODBC/OLEDB).

Comment: @Kevinoid it looks like use only "?" as parameter placeholders in case odbc/oledb. is correct?

Comment: @Sacru2red I believe that's correct.  As far as I know, if you are using the ODBC or OleDB provider for ADO, `?` is the only supported parameter placeholder.

Comment: I am connecting to mssql 2014. With `Provider=SQLNCLI11` in my connection string I still get `Must declare the scalar variable "@name"`. Changing the order of assignment has no effect. I also tried setting `cmd.NamedParameters = True` and `cmd.Prepared = True`.