# Moving from Access backend to SQL Server as be. Efficiency help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

I am working on developing an application for my company. From the beginning we were planning on having a split DB with an access front end, and storing the back end data on our shared server. However, after doing some research we realized that storing the data in a back end access DB on a shared drive isn’t the best idea for many reasons (vpn is so slow to shared drive from remote offices, access might not be the best with millions of records, etc.). Anyways, we decided to still use the access front end, but host the data on our SQL server.

I have a couple questions about storing data on our SQL server. Right now when I insert a record I do it with something like this:

```
Private Sub addButton_Click()

Dim rsToRun As DAO.Recordset
Set rsToRun = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM ToRun")

rsToRun.AddNew
rsToRun("MemNum").Value = memNumTextEntry.Value
rsToRun.Update

memNumTextEntry.Value = Null

End Sub
```

It seems like it is inefficient to have to use a sql statement like SELECT * FROM ToRun and then make a recordset, add to the recordset, and update it. If there are millions of records in ToRun will this take forever to run? Would it be more efficient just to use an insert statement? If so, how do you do it? Our program is still young in development so we can easily make pretty substantial changes. Nobody on my team is an access or SQL expert so any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with SQL Server, use ADO.  It handles server access much better than DAO.

If you are inserting data into a SQL Server table, an `INSERT` statement can have (in SQL 2008) up to 1000 comma-separated `VALUES` groups.  You therefore need only one `INSERT` for each 1000 records.  You can just append additional inserts after the first, and do your entire data transfer through one string:

```
INSERT INTO ToRun (MemNum) VALUES ('abc'),('def'),...,('xyz');
INSERT INTO ToRun (MemNum) VALUES ('abcd'),('efgh'),...,('wxyz');
...
```

You can assemble this in a string, then use an ADO `Connection.Execute` to do the work.  It is frequently faster than multiple DAO *or* ADO `.AddNew`/`.Update` pairs.  You just need to remember to requery your recordset afterwards if you need it to be populated with your newly-inserted data.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually two questions in your post:

**Will `OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM ToRun")` immediately load all recordsets?**

No. By default, DAO's `OpenRecordset` opens a *server-side cursor*, so the data is not retrieved until you actually start to move around the recordset. Still, it's bad practice to select lots of rows if you don't need to. This leads to the next question:

**How should I add records in an attached SQL Server database?**

There are a few ways to do that (in order of preference):

- Use an `INSERT` statment. That's the most elegant and direct solution: You want to insert something, so you execute `INSERT`, not `SELECT` and `AddNew`. As Monty Wild explained in his answer, ADO is prefered. In particular, ADO allows you to use [parameterized commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10352211/87698), which means that you don't have to put-into-quotes-and-escape your strings and correctly format your dates, which is not so easy to do right.
  (DAO also allows you to execute `INSERT` statements (via `CurrentDb.Execute`), but it does not allow you to use parameters.)
- That said, ADO also supports the [AddNew syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677536(v=vs.85).aspx) familiar to you. This is a bit less elegant but requires less changes to your existing code.
- And, finally, your old DAO code will still work. As always: If you *think* you have a performance problem, *measure* if you really have one. Clean code is great, but refactoring has a cost and it makes sense to optimize those places first where it *really* matters. Test, measure... *then* optimize.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems like it is inefficient to have to use a sql statement like SELECT * FROM ToRun and then make a recordset, add to the recordset, and update it. If there are millions of records in ToRun will this take forever to run?

Yes, you *do* need to load something from the table in order to get your Recordset, but you don't have to load any actual data.
Just add a WHERE clause to the query that doesn't return anything, like this:

```
    Set rsToRun = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM ToRun WHERE 1=0")
```

---

#### Both `INSERT` statements and Recordsets have their pros and cons.

With INSERTs, you can insert many records with relatively little code, as shown in [Monty Wild's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22621282/6884).
On the other hand, INSERTs in the basic form shown there are prone to SQL Injection and you need to take care of "illegal" characters like `'` inside your values, ideally by using parameters.

With a Recordset, you obviously need to type more code to insert a record, as shown in your question.
But in exchange, a Recordset does some of the work for you:

For example, in the line `rsToRun("MemNum").Value = memNumTextEntry.Value` you don't have to care about:

- characters like `'` in the input, which would break an INSERT query unless you use parameters
- SQL Injection
- getting the date format right when inserting date/time values