# How to insert datas from textbox to sqltable using vb6.0

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb6

New to vb and tried the below code. searched for solutions in google. But im confused with the results.So im posting in SO.

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim statement As String


Private Sub cmd_update_Click()
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=STPLSVR06.syrmatech.local;Initial Catalog=BVM;Database=Bluestar;uid=sa;pwd=STPLadmin098;"
rs.Open = "insert into Test_Duct values(txt_Board_SrNo.Text,txt_Test_DateTime.Text,txt_User_Name.Text,txt_Communication_status.Text,txt_WatchDog_Status.Text,txt_VoltMes.Text,txt_VoltStatus.Text)"

rs.Close
con.Close
End Sub
```

I used this code from a video and I get an compiler error in "rs.open" statement.
I will be thankful if any of u can give an good insert command or help in finding whats the error.

Comment: I know. Its wrong But im not in a situation to get a book. now. I need to finish it soon. its a order from my boss. Im sorry. But plz help how to insert into table..

Comment: Why book? There is help for ADO, online, like here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678086(v=vs.85).aspx ; there are numerous good samples (not videos!) with explanations. And if you need 'finish it soon', but have no idea about code, then just hire some knowledgeable developer.

Comment: Thanks @Arvo. but i just need know how to use insert command. and need to know what I tried is a waste?

Comment: Search for ADO connection methods, allowing to execute any SQL command. What you tried, is not waste - but usually it is much better first to understand, what you need and what options any framework/API gives to you and only then start to use (or copy-paste) these methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA, ADO.Connection and query parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352211/vba-ado-connection-and-query-parameters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Val only saves numbers.
Try this:

```
Dim usrname As String 'declare as a string

brdSrNo = txt_Board_SrNo.Text
usrname = txt_User_Name.Text
rs.Open "insert into vbtest values(" & brdSrNo & ",'" & usrname & "')", con,adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic

'string should be given in single quotes
```

Remember to add "adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic"
this just a small help from my knowledge. But try to learn before proceeding.

Comment: Thank u somuch @kopika Ill try this.

Comment: only numbers are being saved.. when entering a name the value is automatically stored as 0