# how to bulk insert 255 columns from excel to SQL using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have to bulk insert from Excel to SQL using VBA

I have written a function for that, but it is not working due to string max length.

Can anyone help? below is the code I have written:

```
Dim cn As Object: Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim ProjectName, SourceType As String
ProjectName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Doorset Schedule").Range("B8")
SourceType = "Production Schedule"
''You should probably change Activeworkbook.Fullname to the
''name of your workbook
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
& ActiveWorkbook.FullName _
 & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

cn.Open strCon

s = "INSERT INTO [ODBC;Description=TEST;DRIVER=SQL Server;"
s1 = "SERVER=Admin-hp;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
s2 = "DATABASE=abcd].DoorSchedule ( [ProjectName],[SourceType]"
s3 = ",[A],[B],[C],[D],[E],[F],[G],[H],[I],[J],[K],[L],[M],[N],[O],[P],[Q],[R],[S],[T],[U],[V],[W],[X],[Y],[Z]"
s4 = ",[AA],[AB],[AC],[AD],[AE],[AF],[AG],[AH],[AI],[AJ],[AK],[AL],[AM],[AN],[AO],[AP],[AQ],[AR],[AS],[AT],[AU],[AV],[AW],[AX],[AY],[AZ]"
s5 = ",[BA],[BB],[BC],[BD],[BE],[BF],[BG],[BH],[BI],[BJ],[BK],[BL],[BM],[BN],[BO],[BP],[BQ],[BR],[BS],[BT],[BU],[BV],[BW],[BX],[BY],[BZ]"
s6 = ",[CA],[CB],[CC],[CD],[CE],[CF],[CG],[CH],[CI],[CJ],[CK],[CL],[CM],[CN],[CO],[CP],[CQ],[CR],[CS],[CT],[CU],[CV],[CW],[CX],[CY],[CZ]"
s7 = ",[DA],[DB],[DC],[DD],[DE],[DF],[DG],[DH],[DI],[DJ],[DK],[DL],[DM],[DN],[DO],[DP],[DQ],[DR],[DS],[DT],[DU],[DV],[DW],[DX],[DY],[DZ]"
s8 = ",[EA],[EB],[EC],[ED],[EE],[EF],[EG],[EH],[EI],[EJ],[EK],[EL],[EM],[EN],[EO],[EP],[EQ],[ER],[ES],[ET],[EU],[EV],[EW],[EX],[EY],[EZ]"
s9 = ",[FA],[FB],[FC],[FD],[FE],[FF],[FG],[FH],[FI],[FJ],[FK],[FL],[FM],[FN],[FO],[FP],[FQ],[FR],[FS],[FT],[FU],[FV],[FW],[FX],[FY],[FZ]"
s10 = ",[GA],[GB],[GC],[GD],[GE],[GF],[GG],[GH],[GI],[GJ],[GK],[GL],[GM],[GN],[GO]) "
s11 = " SELECT '" & ProjectName & "','" & SourceType & "',"
s12 = "a.col1 , a.Col2, a.Col3, a.col4, a.col5, a.col6, a.col7, a.col8, a.col9, a.col10, a.col11, a.col12, a.col13, a.col14, a.col15, a.col16, a.col17, a.col18, a.col19, a.col20, a.col21, a.col22, a.col23, a.col24, a.col25, a.col26, a.col27, a.col28, a.col29, a.col30, a.col31, a.col32, a.col33, a.col34, a.col35, a.col36, a.col37, a.col38, a.col39, a.col40, a.col41, a.col42, a.col43, a.col44, a.col45, a.col46, a.col47, a.col48, a.col49, a.col50, a.col51, a.col52, a.col53, a.col54, a.col55, a.col56, a.col57, a.col58, a.col59, a.col60, a.col61, a.col62, a.col63, a.col64, a.col65, a.col66, a.col67, a.col68, a.col69, a.col70, a.col71, a.col72, a.col73, a.col74, a.col75, a.col76, a.col77, a.col78, a.col79, a.col80,"
s13 = "a.col81,a.col82,a.col83,a.col84,a.col85,a.col86,a.col87,a.col88,a.col89,a.col90,a.col91,a.col92,a.col93,a.col94,a.col95,a.col96,a.col97,a.col98,a.col99,a.col100,a.col101,a.col102,a.col103,a.col104,a.col105,a.col106,a.col107,a.col108,a.col109,a.col110,a.col111,a.col112,a.col113,a.col114,a.col115,a.col116,a.col117,a.col118,a.col119,a.col120,a.col121,a.col122,a.col123,a.col124,a.col125,a.col126,a.col127,a.col128,a.col129,a.col130,a.col131,a.col132,a.col133,a.col134,a.col135,a.col136,a.col137,a.col138,a.col139,a.col140,a.col141,a.col142,a.col143,a.col144,a.col145,a.col146,a.col147,a.col148,a.col149,a.col150,a.col151,a.col152,a.col153,"
s14 = "a.col154,a.col155,a.col156,a.col157,a.col158,a.col159,a.col160,a.col161,a.col162,a.col163,a.col164,a.col165,a.col166,a.col167,a.col168,a.col169,a.col170,a.col171,a.col172,a.col173,a.col174,a.col175,a.col176,a.col177,a.col178,a.col179,a.col180,a.col181,a.col182,a.col183,a.col184,a.col185,a.col186,a.col187,a.col188,a.col189,a.col190,a.col191,a.col192,a.col193,a.col194,a.col195,a.col196,a.col197"
s15 = " FROM [Schedule$] a "
s16 = " WHERE a.Col1 Is not Null"



s17 = s + s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7 + s8 + s9 + s10 + s11 + s12 + s13 + s14 + s15 + s16

Debug.Print (s + s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7 + s8 + s9 + s10 + s11 + s12 + s13 + s14 + s15 + s16)

cn.Execute (s + s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7 + s8 + s9 + s10 + s11 + s12 + s13 + s14 + s15 + s16)
```

Comment: This is a perfect place for a parameterized query. You can find examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10353908/4088852) and [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46312/creating-adodb-parameters-on-the-fly).

Comment: I'm not quite sure if a dictionary can surpass the limitation and that may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a quick hack.  I don't have enough information to refine the code.  But is should definitely point you in the right direction. 
 
Your code was trying to connect to the Excel Spreadsheet.  The proper way is to connect to your database and use conn.execute to run your queries.

```
Sub TransferSpreadsheet()
    Dim destinationTable As String, rangeAddress As String, SqlQuery As String
    Dim conn
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Provider = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    conn.Open "C:\Users\tinzina\Datafiles\Spotlights.accdb"

    destinationTable = "TempTable"
    rangeAddress = getTableAddress("Sheet1")
    ExportExceltoAccessTable ThisWorkbook.Name, conn, destinationTable
    ' SqlQuery is the name of a "Saved Query" in your database
    'The "Saved Query" will insert the records from TempTable into whatever table you want
    SqlQuery = ""
    conn.Execute SqlQuery
End Sub


Private Sub ExportExceltoAccessTable(conn, destinationTable, rangeAddress)
    On Error Resume Next
    conn.Execute "DROP TABLE " & destinationTable & ";"
    On Error GoTo 0
    SqlQuery = "SELECT * INTO " & destinationTable & " FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "]." & rangeAddress
    conn.Execute SqlQuery
End Sub

Public Function getTableAddress(wsSheetName)
    Dim r As range
    Set r = Worksheets(wsSheetName).UsedRange
    getTableAddress = "[" & r.Worksheet.Name & "$" & r.Address(False, False) & "]"
End Function
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: thanks. this works. also i have a query. i copied a macro to new file using vba, but when i click on button, it opens the old file from which it is created and pick data from old file. can you please suggest?

Comment: Can you post your code?  I'll have I look at it tomorrow.