# Excel not selected the range specified in query

Tags: vba, excel

i am bulk inserting the worksheet to a temp table in SQL, after that i am calling a stored procedure to move data from temp to main table.

for insert i am using the below statement

```
s = "select * into [" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Control").Range("F2") & "].[" & Environ("username") & "] FROM [ABC$A13:IU5000] "
cn.Execute s
```

the problem is that, even after putting the range in the query, it is only picking upto the last column which have data, which is creating problem.

How can i make it to select exactly the range i specified?

Answer (score 0):

I just posted my code to [Transfer an Excel Range INTO a Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724376/how-to-bulk-insert-255-columns-from-excel-to-sql-using-vba/37725413?noredirect=1#comment62991717_37725413) 
 
This works for me.

```
SELECT * INTO [TagetTable] FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\stackoverflow\test-stub.xlsx].[ABC$A13:IU5000]
```

This is your Query string:

> select * into [F2].[best buy] FROM [ABC$A13:IU5000]

Is F2 the name of the database your are trying to query?  Your missing the filepath in the FROM Clause

Comment: my query is running fine, the only problem is that instead of inserting upto column IU, it only insert upto DD.

Comment: the number of columns varies user to user, i have decided the max range upto IU, but it didnot work.

Comment: I would insert a dummy row of data into Row(14).  That may force the query to insert all the rows and columns.  You can always delete the dummy record from your database afterwards.