# Access: "Too few parameters."

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I know this is a redundant question but could not find a similar scenario to mine.

I have a stored query which, when executed, picks values from the filters on an opened form and display results. All works.

Here is how the query is called:

```
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "qry"
Dim rsReport As New ADODB.Recordset
rsReport.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
rsReport.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rsReport.Open cmd
```

I am trying to use the same query from VBA to create Excel files which can be downloaded or emailed and I am getting a "Too few parameters" error now (while the form is still open). Can anyone set me in the right direction why this is happening please?

Comment: I can understand you have a problem, but we cannot help without any code.

Comment: @Prisoner Wait I will update it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing a query using VBA, you can't reference open forms. You need to explicitly state all parameters.

If you're executing the query using `DoCmd.RunQuery`, you can set parameters using `DoCmd.SetParameter`.

If you're executing the query using `QueryDef.Execute`, you can set parameters using the `QueryDef.Parameters` collection.

If you're executing the query using an `ADODB.Command`, you can set parameters by appending parameters to the `Command.Parameters` collection, in the following way:

`Command.Parameters.Append Command.CreateParameter ("MyParameterName", adInteger, adParamInput)` where `adInteger` is the type. After that, you still need to set the parameter to a value by setting `Command.Parameters("MyParameterName").Value = MyValue`

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352211/vba-ado-connection-and-query-parameters) for info on ADODB parameters. They are a bit more tricky.

All parameters need to be filled in before executing the query.

Comment: the cmd in question is  ADODB.Command object. which method is used?

Comment: One more question, I am referencing the fields directly in query. So I create the parameters with the same naming convention? That is "Forms!form1!textfield"

Comment: Usually, you can just add parameters in order and it will work, but for `ADODB`, I'm not entirely sure. I usually just go for `?` placeholders for parameters in the query.

Comment: I am accepting your answer since it did help me with the direction, and now it's a matter of passing the arguments. Thanks, have a good day