# CRUD Error with ADO

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am in the process of developing an Access 2016 database that has local tables. It will be migrated to SQL Server in future so I am using ADO for data processing.

While testing earlier, my error processing procedure failed to perform a log insert immediately after an error was trapped in the following test CRUD procedure.

```
Public Function updateTransportRate(lngOrigin As Long, lngDestination As Long, dblRate As Double) As Boolean
' check if global error handling is enabled ->
If glbErrorHandling Then On Error GoTo Error_Handler

' declarations ->
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strGUID As String
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Dim p_lRowsUpdated as Integer

    strSQL = "UPDATE tbl_transport " & _
    "SET rate=" & dblRate & ", modify_dtm=Now(), modify_user ='" & Application.CurrentUser & "' " & _
    "WHERE origin=" & lngOrigin & " AND destination=" & lngDestination & ""

    With cnn
        .BeginTrans
        .Execute strSQL, p_lRowsUpdated, dbFailOnError
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            .RollbackTrans
            GoTo Error_Handler
        Else
            .CommitTrans
            If glbDebugMode Then
                Debug.Print "Records Updated : " & p_lRowsUpdated
            End If
            If p_lRowsUpdated > 0 Then updateTransportRate = True Else updateTransportRate = False
            If glbLogApplicationActivity = True And p_lRowsUpdated > 0 Then
                Call addActivityLog(SystemLogType.UpdateRecord, "Updated route " & lngOrigin & " -> " & lngDestination & " with rate: " & dblRate & " in tbl_transport")
            End If
        End If
    End With

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function
Error_Handler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        If glbDebugMode Then
            Select Case DebugOption("Error # " & Err.Number & " was generated by " & Err.Source & " (" & Err.Description & ")")
                Case vbAbort, vbIgnore
                    ProcessError Err.Number, Err.Description, , , "Module", "MAINTENANCE", "Function", "updateTransportRate", Erl, True
                Case vbRetry
                    Stop: Resume 0
            End Select
        Else
            ProcessError Err.Number, Err.Description, , , "Module", "MAINTENANCE", "Function", "updateTransportRate", Erl, True
        End If
    End If
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

Below procedure is used in the above error handler to capture response only while in debug mode:

```
Public Function DebugOption(sErrorMessage As String) As Integer
DebugOption = MsgBox("" & sErrorMessage & "" _
                    & vbCrLf & "Abort - Stop" _
                    & vbCrLf & "Retry - Debug (then press F8 twice to show error line)" _
                    & vbCrLf & "Ignore - Continue with next line", _
                    Buttons:=vbAbortRetryIgnore Or vbCritical Or vbDefaultButton2, Title:=CurrentDb.Properties("AppTitle"))
End Function
```

Debug prompt message for testing only:
[image: Debug prompt message for testing only]

Below is my error processing procedure which accepts a number of parameters and writes the result to a log file:

```
Public Sub ProcessError(Optional strErrNumber As String = vbNullString, _
                        Optional strErrDescription As String = vbNullString, _
                        Optional intErrSeverity As Integer = 0, _
                        Optional strErrState As String = vbNullString, _
                        Optional strErrModuleType As String = vbNullString, _
                        Optional strErrModuleName As String = vbNullString, _
                        Optional strErrProcedureType As String = vbNullString, _
                        Optional strProcedureName As String = vbNullString, _
                        Optional strErrLineNo As String = vbNullString, _
                        Optional blnDisplay As Boolean = True)

' declarations ->
Dim strGUID As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Dim tmpString As String

' build string ->
tmpString = "Error # " & strErrNumber & " (" & strErrDescription & ") on line " & strErrLineNo & " in procedure " & strProcedureName & " of " & strErrProcedureType & " in " & strErrModuleType & " " & strErrModuleName & ""
If glbDebugMode Then Debug.Print tmpString

' check if error logging is enabled ->
If glbErrorLogging Then    

    ' write error log to table ->
    strGUID = CreateGuid

    ' insert log into error table ->
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO system_error_log (error_user, error_number, error_description, error_severity, error_state, " & _
    "error_module_type, error_module_name, error_procedure_type, error_procedure_name, " & _
    "error_line, error_message, rowguid) " & _
    "VALUES('" & Application.CurrentUser & "', '" & strErrNumber & "', '" & strErrDescription & "', " & intErrSeverity & ", '" & strErrState & "', " & _
    " '" & strErrModuleType & "', '" & strErrModuleName & "', '" & strErrProcedureType & "', '" & strProcedureName & "', " & _
    " '" & strErrLineNo & "', '" & Replace(tmpString, "'", "''") & "', '" & strGUID & "')"
    cnn.Execute strSQL, , dbFailOnError **<---- FAILS HERE** 

End If
End Sub
```

Why would the above error processing procedure fail on cnn.Execute strSQL, , dbFailOnError and then display the same error message from earlier CRUD procedure?

cnn.Execute error message:
[image: cnn.Execute error message]

Perhaps I am missing something simple here so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Edit with new source code based on changes for review:

```
Public Function updateRoutePairRate(lngFromLocationNumber As Long, lngToLocationNumber As Long, dblRate As Double) As Boolean
If glbErrorHandling Then On Error GoTo Error_Handler

Dim prm_FromLocationNumber As ADODB.Parameter
Dim prm_ToLocationNumber As ADODB.Parameter
Dim prm_Rate As ADODB.Parameter

    strSQL = "UPDATE tbl_transport " & _
    "SET PalletRate =?, EffectiveDTS =Now(), LastUpdateUserID ='" & Application.CurrentUser & "' " & _
    "WHERE FromLocNo=? AND ToLocNo=?"

    ' set connection and command objects ->
    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    With cmd
        ' create and append parameters ->
        Set prm_Rate = .CreateParameter("PalletRate", adDouble, adParamInput, , dblRate)
        .Parameters.Append prm_Rate
        Set prm_FromLocationNumber = .CreateParameter("FromLocNo", adInteger, adParamInput, , lngFromLocationNumber)
        .Parameters.Append prm_FromLocationNumber
        Set prm_ToLocationNumber = .CreateParameter("ToLocNo", adInteger, adParamInput, , lngToLocationNumber)
        .Parameters.Append prm_ToLocationNumber

        .Parameters.Refresh
        For Each param In cmd.Parameters
            Debug.Print param.Name, param.Value
        Next

        .ActiveConnection = cnn     ' set the connection
        .CommandText = strSQL       ' set command text to SQL
        .CommandType = adCmdText    ' set command type
        .Execute p_lRowsUpdated     ' execute command        
    End With            

    If p_lRowsUpdated > 0 Then updateRoutePairRate = True Else updateRoutePairRate = False

   End With

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Exit Function
Error_Handler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then        
        If glbDebugMode Then
            Select Case DebugOption("Error # " & Err.Number & " was generated by " & Err.Source & " (" & Err.Description & ")")
                Case vbAbort, vbIgnore
                    ProcessError Err.Number, Err.Description, , , "Module", "MAINTENANCE", "Function", "updateRoutePairRate", Erl, True
                Case vbRetry
                    Stop: Resume 0
            End Select
        Else
            ProcessError Err.Number, Err.Description, , , "Module", "MAINTENANCE", "Function", "updateRoutePairRate", Erl, True
        End If
    End If
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Note that `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` won't work if you have an error handler, so you have an unclosed transaction there, but that doesn't make it reproducible for me. Also, your error handler is severely flaud. A lot of error messages (like this one) include single quotes, breaking that SQL. You will need to use parameters in your error handler, else it will generate errors while trying to handle them.

Comment: And `Debug.Print`your `strSQL`to find errors, then use [parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352211/vba-ado-connection-and-query-parameters) instead of just concat.

Comment: @Erik - I found that issue earlier but wanted to address the more pressing issue first. Thanks for noting it though. For the error reproduction, I simply changed the table name to force the error to come through. As you have both pointed out, the issue is clearly being caused by the SQL in my error handling procedure. Perhaps another approach is needed? I am not so familiar with ADO params in Access but I shall give it a try and  post back later if I need any more input. Thanks to both of you for taking the time to review my question.

Comment: I've tried reproducing with the incorrect table names, of course. But that didn't make it reproducible for me. But it might be because of the multiple errors in a single statement. Imo your error handler should always have a valid SQL statement, and using parameters, you can enforce that. That probably avoids this entire problem.

Comment: I just did some dry runs with fixed values in the SQL i stead and it worked fine. You are right, the SQL is the culprit but what got me was that it presented the previous error from the change in table name instead of raising a new error for the flawed SQL in the error handling procedure. I am looking into an escapeDBquotes utility as well as parameters at the moment. As I said I am not familiar with ADO params and commands so I will need to get up to speed with it.

Comment: @Erik thanks a million - Based on the replies, I got it working perfectly with parameters instead. Its a bit more work having to declare, set, and assign the params but imo its much more robust than just using SQL and concatenated variables. Thanks again

Comment: If you're going to use parameters a lot, and want to migrate to SQL server some day, you might want to read [a small tutorial](https://evona.nl/simple-parameterized-queries-using-ado-in-vba/) I wrote about it. The main objective is to make using parameters easier than not using parameters once you have added that code.

Comment: @Erik - Wow! That is some really good work there! Thanks very much for referring me to that. I am currently in the process of converting my code over to use ADO parameters. I hope you don't mind me asking but would you be able to take a quick look at the code I am posting just to make sure I am not missing anything based on your suggestions?