# ASP Function returns unexpected result compared to SQL

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

```
 Function FreeDate(tdate, tindex)
     Set RSD = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
     RSD.Open "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM tTable WHERE fId = " & tindex & " and Convert(datetime, '"& tdate & "') BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate", Conn
     FreeDate = RSD("Total")
     RSD.Close
     Set RSD = Nothing
End Function
```

This function returns 1 with the parameters '2018-12-05' and 31.

The following query on the database results in Total (0) :

```
SELECT Count(*) as Total
FROM tTable
WHERE Convert(datetime, '2018-12-05') BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate AND fId = 31
```

I haven't been able to determine why the same query would not yield the same result.

Comment: Does the query work with an ISO date format (e.g. `WHERE '20181205' BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate AND fId = 31)`? The `CONVERT` is superfluous.

Comment: Also, use strongly typed [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352211/vba-ado-connection-and-query-parameters) to avoid the need to format literals.

Comment: @DanGuzman You are correct on that one. I added `ISODate = Replace(tdate, "-", "")` to check this and the ISODate returns the expected values.