# Inserting names from Excel to SQL Server table (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a simple code to loop through rows and insert values in column A (that is column containing full name) into an SQL Table. Something like this:

```
    For i = 1 to LastRow

    Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [TABLE] [Col1] VALUES ('" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value & "')"

    Next i
```

Issue arises when we have names like [O'Connell], which obviously creates a **Bobby Table** issue.

Are there any clever workarounds to avoid this?

Thanks

N.B. The full name is inserted from another SQL Table. In other words, perhaps a little difficult to edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA, ADO.Connection and query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352211/vba-ado-connection-and-query-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**`Replace`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/replace-function) to remove the problem character:

```
Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [TABLE] [Col1] VALUES ('" & _
    Replace(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value,"'","") & "')"
```

Comment: Brilliant... So in theory I can use this to santize all my strings from (') and (;)... Correct?

Comment: @OdaySalim in theory yes.  And you can nest them `replace(replace(replace(yourstring,"'",""),"*",""),".","")` etc

Comment: How would you nest them?

Comment: if there are any `"` make sure you get those too replace `Chr(34)` with whatever

Comment: One more question dude, why are you sanitizing the "."? I do not see anything malicious with it?