# Put VBA variable in SQL query in excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have this code which works:

```
sqlQuery = ("SELECT monthdata.VAL, monthdata.MONTHVAL, monthdata.GREEN, monthdata.RED, monthdata.RAG, monthdata.CREATOR FROM data LEFT JOIN monthdata ON data.UID = monthdata.DATAUID WHERE [UID] = '" & (IDcell) & "' AND [MONTHVAL] = #" & Format((month1), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#")
```

I'm specifically interested in the end, i.e this bit:

```
[MONTHVAL] = #" & Format((month1), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#")
```

I now have a variable "month1formatted" which is already in mm/dd/yyyy format. So I tried to put this in as a replacement and lose the formatting bit. This is what I ended up with:

```
sqlQuery = ("SELECT monthdata.VAL, monthdata.MONTHVAL, monthdata.GREEN, monthdata.RED, monthdata.RAG, monthdata.CREATOR FROM data LEFT JOIN monthdata ON data.UID = monthdata.DATAUID WHERE [UID] = '" & (IDcell) & "' AND [MONTHVAL] = month1formatted"
```

However, strangley this doesn't work. Am I putting the variable in at the end in the wrong way?

When I print the variable sqlQuery it is printing the text name of the variable `(i.e AND [MONTHVAL] = month1formatted)`, not the value of the variable but I know the variable is set correctly

Comment: How did you declare the month1? it's tricky doing things with dates... i'd declare the variable holding it as string and see if it returns the right format

Comment: Like this ```currentdate = Worksheets("Data").Cells(6, "A").Value
month1 = Format(currentdate, "mm/dd/yyyy")``` Edited my comment above

Comment: You should parameterize your query. Think `IDcell = "' GO; DROP TABLE data --"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing strange about it, you've embedded a variable into your SQL string that your SQL engine knows nothing about.

Replace `Format((month1), "mm/dd/yyyy")` in your original string with `month1formatted` from your new string and the magic will happen.

```vb
sqlQuery = "SELECT monthdata.VAL, monthdata.MONTHVAL, monthdata.GREEN, " & _
           "       monthdata.RED, monthdata.RAG, monthdata.CREATOR " & _
           "  FROM data " & _
           "       LEFT JOIN monthdata ON data.UID = monthdata.DATAUID " & _
           " WHERE [UID] = '" & IDcell & "' " & _
           "  AND [MONTHVAL] = #" & month1formatted & "#"
```

Also, no need for the enclosing parenthesis `()` around your string literal, and I formatted it with line breaks to ease readability.

Oh, and do as Comintern instructed and parameterize the query! This [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10353908/2344413) is a good example of how to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The use of parameterized queries (as "instructed" by the "Comintern") is a mean of avoid (or reduce the occurrence of) SQL-injection... Is highly recomended to follow the recommendations of the "accepted answer"

Comment: @ÁlvaroGustavoLópez - thank you for clarifying that. I should have done so.

Comment: I've seen in industrial software -supposedly written by professionals in the field- to make this mistake (SQL injection)... Indeed, I have had a dispute with a supplier about this matter. The experience, after all -even in such a "modern" area- is a good teacher... it isn't?