# VBA get output parameter from stored procedure

Tags: excel, vba, t-sql

I have this code

```
 ' Insert item into database
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn

        .CommandText = "exec myschema.usp_procedure" _
        & "'" & user & "'," _
        & "''" ' output id

        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandTimeout = 300
        .Execute

        Dim outputId As Integer
        outputId = cmd.Parameters("outputId").Value

    End With
```

I am getting error

```
Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal
```

Whats wrong ? How can i retrieve the `@outputId int OUTPUT` parameter ?

- The stored procedure is executed properly, i can see new items in database

**another try**

```
Dim outputId As Integer
     With cmd
            .ActiveConnection = conn

            .CommandText = "exec edi.usp_ImportOrderHeader" _
            & "'" & user & "'," _
            & "''"

            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("outputId", adNumeric, adParamOutput, , outputId)

            .CommandType = adCmdText
            .CommandTimeout = 300

            .Execute
        End With
```

store procedure execute without error, but outputId is zero :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA, ADO.Connection and query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352211/vba-ado-connection-and-query-parameters)

Comment: @ashleedawg but that is input parameter, i need output.