# CONVERSION FAILED WHEN CONVERTING DATA/OR time from character string VBA to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm trying to upload an Excel file into a SQL Server table, but I get this error:

> CONVERSION FAILED WHEN CONVERTING DATA/OR time from character string VBA TO SQL SERVER

My source table has format date and my destination table have format date to.

What should I do to make this code work

I'm trying using `CDATE()` but it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub EventData_Click()

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
cs = "DRIVER=SQL SERVER;"
cs = cs & "DATABASE=MAGANG;"
cs = cs & "SERVER=FELIX"

conn.Open cs, "", ""

sqlcmd = "CREATE TABLE Event_Data(ID Varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY, EVENT Varchar(255),DATE DATE);"

On Error GoTo errormastertable
conn.Execute sqlcmd
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing

errormastertable:

    Dim l_row As Long
   
    Dim s_ID As String
    Dim s_EVENT As String
    Dim s_DATE As Date
 
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
cs = "DRIVER=SQL SERVER;"
cs = cs & "DATABASE=MAGANG;"
cs = cs & "SERVER=FELIX"

    With Workbooks("Event_Data").Sheets("4-Event_Data")

conn.Open cs, "", ""
        l_row = last_row_with_data(1, ActiveSheet)
   
    For i = 2 To l_row
   
        s_ID = .Cells(i, 1)
        s_EVENT = .Cells(i, 2)
        s_DATE = .Cells(i, 3)
                               
        sqlcmd = "insert into dbo.Event_Data (ID,EVENT,DATE) values ('" & s_ID & "', '" & s_EVENT & "', '" & s_DATE & "')"
        conn.Execute sqlcmd
         Next
          conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing

    End With
   
    Workbooks("Event_Data").Close savechanges:=False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Parameterize your query and the problem will go away

Comment: [VBA, ADO.Connection and query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10353908/2029983) is a good place to start

Comment: how can i apply that to my code ?

Comment: Please check the link Larnu provided, it contains a pretty good example. If you get stuck, don't hesitate to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Numbers are generally without symbols
2. Characters have single quotes before and after
3. The datetime format is prefixed with # before and after the data.

---

```
sqlcmd = "insert into dbo.Event_Data (ID,EVENT,DATE) values ('" & s_ID & "', '" & s_EVENT & "', '" & s_DATE & "')"
```

to (In case of access file)

```
sqlcmd = "insert into dbo.Event_Data (ID,EVENT,DATE) values ('" & s_ID & "', '" & s_EVENT & "', #" & s_DATE & "#)"
```

But (in case of MSSQL)

```
  sqlcmd = "insert into dbo.Event_Data (ID,EVENT,DATE) values ('" & s_ID & "', '" & s_EVENT & "', cast('" & s_DATE & "' as datetime) )"
```

Comment: thanks bro but im but my problem already solved with this code ```_date = Year(s_DATE) & "/" & PadLeft(Month(s_DATE), 2, "0") & "/" & PadLeft(Day(s_DATE), 2, "0")```

Comment: @LixFelix, My answer was a bit confusing. mssql needs to convert datetime data to another format. Corrected the answer.