# VBA ADODB SQL query returns "Automation error" when reading a variable from cell, works well when a value is assigned in VBA code

Tags: sql, vba, sql-update, mariadb, adodb

Debugger returns automation error when running the following :

```
Private Sub setDB()

Dim SQL As String
Dim Var As String

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

conn.Open "DRIVER={MariaDB ODBC 3.0 Driver}" _
& ";SERVER=" & "localhost" _
& ";DATABASE=" & "pbx" _
& ";USER=" & "root" _
& ";PASSWORD=" & "r00t" _

Var = Worksheets(3).Range("B2").Value  

SQL = "UPDATE ps_product SET ean13='" & Var & "' WHERE id_product=12"
conn.Execute (SQL)
```

However when I assign a value to Var like this: `Var=10`, the code runs fine. Am I missing something here? I have searched on the internet for several days and I didn't find anything similar. Can some1 help or maybe send a link to a similar issue, please?

Comment: What does `Debug.Print Worksheets(3).Range("B2").Value` return?

Comment: Curious, in your many days search, did you run into a concept called SQL parameterization?

Comment: Hi Parfait, no, I am seeing this concept for the first time. So I researched a bit and found some useful information here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352211/vba-ado-connection-and-query-parameters and in "Using a Connection object" part here: [link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/creating-and-executing-a-simple-command?view=sql-server-ver15. Using a connection object or command object seems to behave the same.

Comment: Nevermind got it to work after all. Thx for the hint with the parametrization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider parameterization, the preferred method to bind application layer values to executed SQL queries. ADO supports this approach with [Command parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-ver15). This avoids messy concatenation, quote punctation, and escape needs if string value contains special characters like single quotes.

```vb
Dim Sql As String, Var As String

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command              ' NEW OBJECT TO INITIALIZE

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

conn.Open "DRIVER={MariaDB ODBC 3.0 Driver}" _
           & ";SERVER=" & "localhost" _
           & ";DATABASE=" & "pbx" _
           & ";USER=" & "root" _ 
           & ";PASSWORD=" & "r00t" _

' PREPARED STATEMENT WITH PLACEHOLDER (NO QUOTES OR CONCATENATION)
Sql = "UPDATE ps_product SET ean13=? WHERE id_product=12"  

' CONVERT TO NEEDED TYPE 
Var = CStr(Worksheets(3).Range("B2").Value)

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandText = Sql
    .CommandType = adCmdText

    ' BIND PARAMS AND DEFINE TYPE AND LENGTH
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("prm", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Var)

    ' EXECUTE ACTION
    .Execute
End cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

The query is working when the desired cell is passed as a parameter. (Thx to @Parfait for the hint)
Some useful info which helped me figure this out can be found here:

[VBA, ADO.Connection and query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352211/vba-ado-connection-and-query-parameters)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/creating-and-executing-a-simple-command?view=sql-server-ver15
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/passing-parameters-to-a-named-command?view=sql-server-ver15

```
Working example:

Private Sub setDB()

Dim Cm As New ADODB.Command
Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

Test = Worksheets(3).Range("B2").Value

CommandText = "UPDATE ps_product SET ean13=? WHERE id_product=12;"

conn.Open "DRIVER={MariaDB ODBC 3.0 Driver}" _
& ";SERVER=" & "localhost" _
& ";DATABASE=" & "pbx" _
& ";USER=" & "root" _
& ";PASSWORD=" & "r00t" _

Cm.CommandText = CommandText
Cm.CommandType = adCmdText
Cm.Name = "Var"
Set Cm.ActiveConnection = conn

conn.Var Test, Rs

End Sub
```