# VB6 Error : Method 'Refresh' of object 'IAdodc' failed

Tags: vb6

I am using data-grid to display the database and used a combo-box and textbox to search the data field I got the error as `"Syntax error in FROM clause"` and then

`"Runtime Error '-2147217900(80040e14)' Method Refresh' of object 'IAdodc' Failed."`

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
   If Category.Text = "Name" Then
      Showdata.RecordSource = "Select * from EmployeeRegisteration where Name = '" + Display.Text + "'"
      Showdata.Refresh
      Showdata.Caption = Showdata.RecordSource
   End If
End Sub
```

I've created many other forms but never faced such error.

Comment: Which SQL are you using (SQL server, MySQL, etc)?  Also the `Name` field could be causing the error.  Try putting brackets around the field so that the query instead is as follows: 
`"Select * from EmployeeRegisteration where [Name] = '" + Display.Text + "'"`

Comment: Make sure Display.Text doesn't also include a quote (').

In general you should refrain from creating your SQL statement with pure string concatenation. Best practice is to use a [Parameterized Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352211/vba-ado-connection-and-query-parameters) for that, which would take care of proper string santization.

And personally I'd use `&` to concat strings. Makes it more obvious what's going an

Comment: You should form the SQL string as a separate variable, set a breakpoint just after, and see what's in it. That will show the problem.

Comment: Is the misspelling of EmpolyeeRegistration deliberate?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue in VB6 with ADO in SQL Server.
Changing the LockType from adLockOptimistic to adLockReadOnly fixed it.
Hope it helps someone!