# always showing while searching data type mismatch in criteria expression and method refresh of object IADODC failed in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

This is the main code showing that every time I search data type mismatch in criteria expression and method refresh of object IADODC failed this was showing

```
Private Sub gosearch_Click()
    adogrid.RecordSource = "Select *from StudentsInformation where IDNo='" + Text1.Text + "' or Name='" + Text1.Text + "'"
    adogrid.Refresh
    If adogrid.Recordset.EOF Then
        MsgBox "Record Not Found, Enter any other IDNo or Name", vbCritical, "Message"
    Else
        adogrid.Caption = adogrid.RecordSource
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to lookup people by name or some numeric ID. If `IDNo` is defined as a numeric field in your database, you will always get an error when searching by name. You should first check if the content of `Text1` is numeric and use a different query:

```
If IsNumeric(Text1.Text) Then
    adogrid.RecordSource = "Select * from StudentsInformation where IDNo=" + Text1.Text
Else
    adogrid.RecordSource = "Select * from StudentsInformation where Name='" + Text1.Text + "'"
End If
```

Concatenating a SQL statement like this is not recommended (see Why reason in [How and Why to Use Parameterized Queries](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries/ba-p/383483)). Look at the following question regarding converting this code to use parameterized queries: [VBA, ADO.Connection and query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352211/vba-ado-connection-and-query-parameters).